# What happens when libraries are not "cleaned up" in c++ upon exit

Tags: c++, linux, exit

I am running linux, and simply wondering what actually happens post process death to the code of libraries not "cleaned up" by running a terminate function on them or something of the like. I have seen people implement specific cleanup on exit functions, and others not do it.

Comment: @chris for example, connections to a sound library. Just local code with a `terminate()` function or something of the like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what cleaning up you expect.  All local OS resources (memory, open files/sockets, etc) that the library had opened will be closed/freed.  This occurs even if you don't call the associated cleanup functions (free/delete, fclose/close, etc).

However, non-OS resources (such as a transaction started on a server) will not be auto-cleaned.  This occurs as it's impossible for the OS to know what to do in this situation.  Well written servers will handle these cases graciously.

Also, libraries can "hide" certain cleanup functions if the program exits normally.

Comment: "Well written servers will handle these cases graciously." - which means that the transaction will be rollbacked, which is not what you usually want.

Comment: I meant more that resources are cleaned up.  Of course such behaviour should be checked, and if it is not wanted appropriate action should be taken.
It is better to have unfinished transactions rollback then commit, so that would be the "safe" behaviour.  Even if you lose finished ones.

Answer (score 2):

#### It depends...

... on the resource type.

**Best Practice**

*Do free* file descriptors. (However the OS *will* close them for you.)

*Do close* buffered files and db connections. (However standard output buffers will be flushed on *exit(3)* or on a return from *main()*.

*But do not free* allocated memory right before exit. This is a big waste of time and can result in reading back pages that will never be used.